# Basic ember.js template concepts

Tags: templates, view, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to understand the basic concepts of ember.js and how the whole template/view stuff works together (and some best practices), but, I really have problems to find answers to my questions.... So, maybe, one of you can help me...

1. ["Getting started"](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_getting-started) says: "You can use Ember.View to render a Handlebars template and insert it into the DOM" and it suggests the usage of view.append(). I downloaded to getting started kit and there is a template, a view and it's beeing displayed without a view.append(). Why?
2. I tried to extend the template with a placeholder {{ message }} added a attribute with the same name to the view, and assigned a value, but its not rendered. Why?

Can someone please bring some light to me... Many thanks in advance. Links and good Stackoverflow threads are very welcome.

Some code examples:

index.html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
<h1>Hello from Ember.js</h1>
</script>
```

app.js

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application',
  message : 'Hallo Du'
});
```

If I change 'application' to 'application_", it will still be rendered... So, why do I define a template name?

Best regards
Peter

Comment: It's difficult to tell why your attribute isn't showing without your code. Can you add some to the question or to [jsdiffle](http://jsfiddle.net). Additionally, you might wanna look into [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/hEx84/) (sorry, it takes a few extra seconds to load on jsfiddle, i'll fix that later)

Comment: Sorry, MilkyWayJoe, I've added a short example.

Comment: I think `application` is the default template name, so if you don't define `data-template-name` it will automatically be application. Now looking at your view and template, I don't see `{{message}}` as part of the template. Another important point, after 1.0pre, to display view attributes/properties you have to do `{{view.YourAttributeName}}`, so you might wanna try that as `{{view.message}}` in your handlebars template. But wait, have you tried with simply `{{message}}` yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried {{ message }} and {{ App.ApplicationView.message }}, but the second one seems strange to me because I thought the template<->view relation was set up with 'templateName' in the view...

Comment: Peter, have you had the time to try something similar to the code in my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, in Ember 1.0pre (and newer releases), to display view attributes/properties you have to do `{{view.YourAttributeName}}`, so you have to user `{{view.message}}` in your handlebars template. So here's what you have to do in your js:

```
App = null;

$(function() {

    App = Em.Application.create();

    App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
      templateName: 'application',
      message : 'Hallo Du'
    });
})
```

And here's the html page with the template:

```
<body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h1>Hello from Ember.js</h1>
         {{view.message}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js" ></script>
</body>​
```

Check this very basic fiddle with the code above working: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/MwXjG/